# Extract from Timespan Totalhours and Minutes

Tags: c#, timespan

I get from `TimeSpan.TotalHours` 24,75 hours. 
How can I convert this to get the full and not roundes hours (=24) plus the minutes (0,75hours = 45 minutes)? So the result should be hours = 24 and minutes = 45

I tried to convert it to string and make substring but I would like to know if there is a better way than this.

```
string test = Reststunden.TotalHours.ToString().Substring(Reststunden.TotalHours.ToString().IndexOf(","),3).Replace(",", "");
double Minuten = Convert.ToInt16(test) * 0.6;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well just round the total hours appropriately by casting, and then use the `Minutes` property:

```
int hours = (int) timeSpan.TotalHours;
int minutes = timeSpan.Minutes;
```

If you'll ever have a negative `TimeSpan`, you should think about what you want the results to be and add appropriate tests - you may well find it doesn't do what you want with the simple code above.

Comment: Why use TotalHours instead of Hours?

Comment: Because you could have TotalHours be 49. Hours would be 1 in this case. No? Whenever I see @Jon Skeet answer a question that question is answered. Kudos, my friend.

Comment: @o_weisman: Exactly what Max said, basically. Read the docs for the `Hours` property and compare that with the OP's request.

Comment: Right, didn't take days into account. :)

Comment: Simply perfect, sometimes my brain can't see the simplest solution :)

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(24.75);
var h = System.Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours);
var m = (ts.TotalHours - h) * 60;
```

Or even:

```
var h = (int) (ts.TotalMinutes / 60);
var m = ts.TotalMinutes % 60;
```

Comment: it's rounding the hours, I need them unrounded

Comment: I still like Skeet's answer better:-)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to display the total hours and minutes in the following format HH:mm.
With the help of the other answers I came to the following result:

```
var end = DateTime.Now;
var duration = end - StartUpTime;
var h = (int)(duration.TotalMinutes / 60);
var m = (int)(duration.TotalMinutes % 60);
var text = $"{h:D2}:{m:D2}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to display the total hours and minutes in the following format HH:mm.
Use this below extention method.

```
public static string TohhmmFormatString(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    string totalHours = ((int)timeSpan.TotalHours).ToString();
    string minutes = timeSpan.Minutes.ToString();
    if (timeSpan.Seconds == 59 && (timeSpan.Milliseconds == 999 || timeSpan.Microseconds == 999))
    {
        if (timeSpan.Minutes + 1 == 60)
        {
            minutes = "00";
            totalHours = ((int)timeSpan.TotalHours + 1).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            minutes = (timeSpan.Minutes + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
    return $"{totalHours}:{minutes}";
 }
```